# Access 2010 - Create VBA Macro generate Text File

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table with about 900 records. A sample record looks like this:

Field Names:

```
ID  FNN DSLAM_ID    SHORT_CODE  PORT_TYPE   PANEL   SLOT    CHANNEL CONNECTION_TYPE SERVICE_TYPE    PVCID   CHANNEL_TYPE    PROD_CODES
```

Record 1:

```
1   A99TEST9999 QXXXXENNNN  ABCDE   DSL48P  1   11  38  ABC ADSL    RANDOMIDXXYY    N   ADESP=NNNNNNN_ABCDEFG_L2PPP
```

I'd like to build a text file, where for each record it builds a new line and inputs a specific field as a variable.

An example Line:

```
FNN="[FNN]" : ACTION="" : SERVICE_TYPE="[CONNECTION_TYPE]" : NE_ID="[DSLAM_ID]", NE_DEFN="[SERVICE_TYPE]", PORT="[PANEL] / [SLOT] / [CHANNEL]"
```

I've seen people write scripts to create Router Configurations before and essentially this is what I want to do to build a Mass Configuration File for an application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the recordset object and then do something like this:

```
Open "yourfilename.txt" for Output as #1
While not (recordset.eof) 
  Print #1, "FNN=" & recordset.fields("FNN").value (add the rest of your string here...)
  recordset.movenext
Wend
Close #1
```

Technically, instead of "#1" you should grab the file number by using the FreeFile() function.